# Filter using a new column created in a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a column named CREATED_DATE that converts the timestamp to date and time with the results being:

11/14/2018 19:28:56

when I try to filter the query in the WHERE clause using- AND CREATED_DATE= TRUNC(SYSDATE)

I get "ORA-00904: "CREATED_DATE": invalid identifier"

How can I resolve this issue?

```
SELECT
            DATE '1899-12-30' + WRITETIMESTAMP AS CREATED_DATE,
            ID,
            USERTYPEID,
            PROFILEID,
            NAME,
            ADDRESS1,
            ADDRESS2,
            CITY,
            COUNTY,
            STATE,
            ZIP,
            COUNTRY,
            LATITUDE,
            LONGITUDE,

            COMMENT1,
            COMMENT2,
            ROUTEGROUPID ||','|| ROUTEID AS RouteSegment
FROM t.table 1
JOIN t.table 2  ON 1.ID = 2.LOCATIONID
WHERE ID LIKE '01%' OR ID LIKE '07%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_DATE` rather concatenating the date with timestamp to translate it from one type to other as in where clause correctly pointed error as invalid identifier.

```
   SELECT TO_DATE(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD 
   HH:MM:SS') FROM TABLE ......
```

This will read the data in the format as specified or if you want to show the data as Use `TO_CHAR`

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD 
   HH:MM:SS') FROM TABLE .......
```

or the interesting one `TO_TIMESTAMP` the most effective for timestamp date

```
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD 
   HH:MM:SS') FROM TABLE .......
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the expression.  Presumably, you want:

```
TRUNC(DATE '1899-12-30' + WRITETIMESTAMP, 'DAY') = TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY')
```

Comment: I did this and got the following error: ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers

Comment: Thanks you,this runs the query but it wont filter to only show current day. It still pulls in all the data.